# if div height is greater than 100 move exceed text to another div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have 2 contenteditable div, i want it that if div (div A) height become greater than 100px move exceed text to another div (div B).

I
am
learning
(for example, here div height is greater than 100px, move the "javascript" to another div)
javascirpt.

and next time if more text it added to the div , move text base on height again.

Testing again
I
am
(for example, here div height is greater than 100px, move the "learning javascript" to another div)
learning
javascirpt.

jsFiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/mhabib555/zvq96xy6/2/

```js
function checkHeight(){
    var divA = document.getElementById('a');
    var divB = document.getElementById('b');
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = divA.clientHeight;

    if(divA.clientHeight>100) {
         //move the exceeded text to div B
    }
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable='true' id='a' onkeyup='checkHeight()'>Edit Me</div>
<div contenteditable='true' id='b'>Edit Me 2</div>

<div>Current Height :  <span id='status'></span></div>
```

Comment: Check following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zvq96xy6/4/). Still needs few tweaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could do something with setting the focus on the div B when a certain height exceeds div A.

```
if(divA.clientHeight > 100) {
    document.getElementById('b').focus;
    // some more code`
}
```

Comment: focus works if there is no preceding text. But if there is preceding text then it can't move

Comment: Ahh oke. Just another idea: what you could do it to split your text where it exceeds the amount of characters that come across with the max height. Then you could append the text that exceeds this amount into the second div.